# Keep users from changing field but allow batch apex to edit it

Tags: batch, custom-field, permissions, schedulebatch

I have a field that I want to display on a Contact record however I do not want users to modify this value. The catch is that I have a batch apex job that is updating this field periodically to keep it up to date. So I will need the batch apex job to be able to modify it but no one else. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the field Read-Only for all profiles. Apex Code (e.g. Batchable Apex Code) doesn't respect field level security out of the box, so your batch class will still be able to run without field level security errors. This will prevent any attempts from non-administrators to modify the field; System Administrators can still modify the field's value because of the Edit Read Only Fields permission that comes standard on the System Administrator profile.

Comment: Is there a way to uncheck this permission on their profile? Either using metadata api or some other method

Comment: @LouisPujol The standard system administrator profile basically can't be edited, except for field level security. This is basically true of the six standard profiles. You could create a custom System Administrator profile and assign that profile to all users that you want to be administrators. I don't know of many Enterprise organizations that prefer using the standard System Administrator profile simply because it's usually not "just right" for most cases.

Comment: @LouisPujol On the other hand, if they have Customize Application and Manage Users, they can go in and reactivate the ability to edit read-only fields and/or simply modify the field's security directly. Basically, you need to "trust" your administrators, because they *can* circumvent any restriction given enough administrative power.

Comment: Okay thanks @sfdcfox. It won't be game breaking for them to edit it. I just don't want them calling Support and asking why their fields got changed back and their work was undone.

Answer (score 2):

Make the field read only in page layout level if people wont use dataloader.

[image]

Comment: Would this still allow system-admins to edit this field?

Comment: System admins have View all and modify all Permissions as default Profile permission.  So they field would be accessible by System admins.

Comment: you can create two different page layout one is for sys admin and another for other users. you can make field as read only on one page layout but you can make that field editable on sys admin page layout.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the sys admins profile so that they cannot edit read only fields?